# SEO impact of CSS Stylesheet dynamic loading with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, seo

Because my webpages are a bit heavy, I decided to use a preloader. The purpose of a preloader is to show some content before the main content loads, engaging the user from the start. Therefore it is very important to show preloader ASAP.

There is a slight problem though. Browser will typically wait for all CSS to be loaded before attempting to display and render HTML. This can be problematic if the document contains several biggish stylesheets.

So, my solution was thus:

```
<!-- In the head: -->
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/big-css1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/big-css2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/big-css3.css">
</noscript>
    <script>
        function LoadCSS(path) {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                link = document.createElement('link');
            link.setAttribute('href', path);
            link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
            link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
            head.appendChild(link);
        }
    </script>
<style>
/*preloader CSS is here*/
</style>

...
</head>
<body>
<div id="preloader">
Some nice content here
</div>

<!-- Main content starts below: -->
<div id="wrapper">
<script>
//hide main content until its loaded
//use JS and not CSS to support those with JS disabled
var el_preloader = document.getElementById("preloader");
var el_wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
el_preloader.style.display = "block";
el_wrapper.style.display = "none";
LoadCSS('/big-css1.css');
LoadCSS('/big-css2.css');
LoadCSS('/big-css3.css');
</script>
...

<!-- After jQuery has been loaded -->
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "block";
    jQuery('#preloader').fadeOut(1000, function () {
        jQuery('#preloader').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

So, basically, if the use supports JavaScript, then JavaScript handles loading of stylesheets, and if JS is turned off, then the stuff inside the `<noscript>` tag is parsed and thus stylesheets are loaded normally.

This setup works fine in modern browsers, however I am not sure what impact it will have on SEO, considering Google and others are now evaluating user experience on the websites, and for that they need to parse CSS. Are they smart enough to render the website correctly with this solution? ARe there any adverse impacts on SEO with preloaders in general?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK some crawlers have _some_ javascript support, I don't know if this helps you with your question.